# What is the font in this image?

Tags: fonts

Can any one recognize the font used in this terminal?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to see exactly what font and size it is if you opened the terminal's settings from the menu?

Comment: This is an image i found on the web, not mine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identifying fonts is not in scope.

Comment: Maybe is [Clear Sans Light](https://01.org/clear-sans/downloads)

Comment: There are enough resources in the web where you can upload images to automatically identify the font.

Comment: @Philippos I've tried some of them, but they were not enough precise. They've given me completely wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/), which I think is the current GNOME default mono-spaced font.